# extend item then remove item in nested list in python

Tags: python, list, nested, extend

I am trying to classification a nested list in python, I have huge list and I haven't succeeded yet because of item index error. My goal is that if two items in list have same member then extend item1 with item2 and remove item2. I don't have enough experience on python. I hope you can help

```
My pseudo code

L = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 13], [6, 7], [2, 8],[3, 10, 11], [12, 13]]

for i in range(len(L)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(L)):
        if i!=j and set(L[i]) & set(L[j]) != set():
            L[i].extend(L[j])
            L.remove(L[j])

expected L = [[0,1], [6, 7], [2, 3, 2, 8, 3, 10, 11], [4, 5, 13, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
L = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 13], [6, 7], [2, 8],[3, 10, 11], [12, 13]]

out = []
while L:
    current = L.pop(0)
    out.append(current)
    tmp = []    
    for v in L:
        if set(v).intersection(current):
            current.extend(v)
        else:
            tmp.append(v)
    L = tmp

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3, 2, 8, 3, 10, 11], [4, 5, 13, 12, 13], [6, 7]]
```

---

EDIT: Version 2:

```
L = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9],[10, 11], [1,3,5,7,9,11]] 
    
out = []
while L:
    current = L[0]
    while True:
        tmp = []
        for i, v in enumerate(L[1:], 1):
            if set(v).intersection(current):
                current.extend(L.pop(i))
                break
            else:
                tmp.append(v)
        else:
            break
    out.append(current)
    L = tmp

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

For `L = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 13], [6, 7], [2, 8],[3, 10, 11], [12, 13]]` prints:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3, 2, 8, 3, 10, 11], [4, 5, 13, 12, 13], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: Thak you Andrej Kesely,  your approach is very distinguished but If I take a interesting list as follow then I would not  take desirable output.
L = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9],[10, 11], [1,3,5,7,9,11]]

Comment: Thank you so much  Andrej Kesely again. I have tried and I got the satisfactory results..